# Exception Handling in Spring Rest Services

Tags: spring

I have two controllers in my application. One is the Rest Service Controller and other is normal Spring mvc controller which finally renders a jsp.
Whenever any exception is raised in Spring mvc controller, it should show me an Error Page.
Whenever any exception is raised in Rest Controller, then i have to set the Response Status and exception message in the body.

I've written 2 ExceptionResolvers which handles the exceptions and sets the status code and exception message in it and other one shows the Error page. The one which sets the Status code has order 0 and other one has order as 1. However the problem here is whenever an exception is raised from Web Controller it goes into same ExceptionResolver with order 0 and Http Status code is set in response which messes up everything. In this case instead of application error page, status code and message is displayed to client.

How to handle this situation?

Comment: You can throw distinct Exceptions from respective controllers because the exception resolvers have no way to distinguish the controller from where exception is raised.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver is great ^^